# Jquery flot plugin is not plotting graph according to the date

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, graph

I'm trying to plot a graph using jquery flot plugin with JSON data. What I need to do is.

- When the page loads it will makes an ajax call and receives json data from the server.
- from the received json I need to add 'x' and 'y' axis label. And I want to draw the graph
- according to points in json data.
- 'Y' axis must have values from 0 to 100
- 'X' axis should have only json data value

My Script is:

```
    //var maxDate = new Date();
    //var minDate = new Date();
    var options = {
        series: {
            lines: {
                show: true
            },
            points: {
                show: true
            }
        },
        grid: {
            hoverable: true,
            clickable: true
        },
        xaxis: { //min: minDate.setMonth(maxDate.getMonth() - 12),
                //max: maxDate,
                mode: "time",
                monthNames: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"],
                timeformat: "%b(%Y)" 
        },
        yaxis: {
            min: 0,
            max: 100,
            ticks: 10
        }
    var data = [];
    var placeholder = $("#trigo");

        var dataurl = 'cprogress.php?action=overall';

        // then fetch the data with jQuery
        function onDataReceived(series) {
            data.push(series);
            $.plot(placeholder, data, options);
            setData(data);
         }

        $.ajax({
            url: dataurl,
            method: 'GET',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: onDataReceived
        });
```

Now my graph Looks like this
[image]

And the JSON

```
[["2013-11-05",8.3333333333333],["2013-12-05",0]]
```

What I want to print is 
**November(2013) and December(2013) and have to draw graph from 8.33 to 0** Now it is print *January(1970)* Why I don't know.

Please any one help me to solve this issue. I'm struggling to solve this from two days. Thanks...

Comment: The JSON you wrote is actually what your `cprogress.php?overall` page is printing or is what you _want_ to have? The question may seem stupid but I'm just asking if your PHP is correct.

Comment: @ Kevin Cittadini I have `jquery.flot.time.js`. that reason only my graph showing `january(1970)` And What you mean't by **documentation reports mode: null **

Comment: @ Kevin Cittadini My `php` is correct. The result will change depending on the situations. That reason I wan't to get the result in `json`

Comment: Nothing, I was just quoting the documentation line. Yes, i figured it out later. Anyway take a look at this [**Time series data**](https://github.com/flot/flot/blob/master/API.md#time-series-data). The date must be in Javascript Timestamp but you're returning a date in this format `yyyy-mm-dd` . Javascript Timestamp is Unix Timestamp multipied by 1000 ( the page says that too )

Comment: @Kevin Cittadini  Thank you for your suggestion. Now it is working well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***[`jsFiddle Demo`](http://jsfiddle.net/LjGQY/)***

There are a couple of things going on here. First, the date that flot expects is going to be in millseconds since 1970. When a string is passed, it just evaluates that to basically -1000, 0, and 1000 for your string input. The result is three dates, all basically at January 1970.

So you will need a little helper function that can manipulate these date inputs for you.

```
function formatTime(input){
 for( var i = 0; i < input.length; i++ ){
  var date = input[i][0];
  input[i][0] = new Date(date).getTime();
 }
 return input;
}
```

You can call this with the series result from your ajax call

```
function onDataReceived(series) {
 series = formatTime(series);//called here
 data.push(series);
 $.plot(placeholder, data, options);
 //setData(data);not shown in question
}
```

So that will fix the "times" issue. There is however, one other obstacle I noticed. Once you do that, the format of the graph will show both labels right next to each other. This is because (as can be observed if the customization is commented out) flot expects to show the range by days. So the change of the month (at the very end of the day range) is the position where both November and December are shown. To overcome this, I would suggest something along the lines of using

```
autoscaleMargin: 1,
```

for your x-axis customization. The demo also includes a small click example (mostly included so that you can verify the data points are accurate).

[image: example]

references examined:

- https://github.com/flot/flot/blob/master/API.md
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime
- https://raw.github.com/mde/timezone-js/master/src/date.js
- http://flot.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/API.txt

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I already solved my issue from Kevin Cittadini's suggestion, I just had to multiply the `strtotime` with `1000` in my `php` script. It solved my issue. Thank you for more  well described answer.

Comment: I need a small help regarding this graph. I want to set the x-axis ticks in the graph according to the data. for example if may data is `2013-11-05,  2013-12-05, 2014-01-05` then I want only `November(2013),December(2013),January(2013)`.